How to move address below name while keeping classic style in moderncv?
How can I move the address below the name while maintaining the 'classic' style instead of the banking style?

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic} % <=============================================
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}         
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}  
\mobile{mobile phone}
\phone{phone (optional)} 
\email{email address} 
\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} 


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Content}

\end{document}


The components for the header is created during the call to \maketitle, so it's not easy to change. Easiest would be to extract the components and create a header manually.
Under the classic style, the header construction is contained with moderncvheadi.sty, where the two components in question are stored in boxes. They are \makecvheadnamebox and \makecvheaddetailsbox. Here are the definitions that showcases their construction:
\savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
  \addressfont\color{addresscolor}%
  \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\fi%
  \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@born}}{}{\makenewline\bornsymbol\@born}%
    \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@homepageprotocol}{http}}{\httplink{\@homepage}}{\httpslink{\@homepage}}}%
    \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
  \end{tabular}
}
% ...
\savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
    \if@left\raggedright\fi%
    \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
    \firstnamestyle{\@firstname}~\lastnamestyle{\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}}%

Note how some of the formatting depends on whether you're using left or right for the class option. The default is left, which necessarily sets the "details" portion of the header right-aligned (\raggedleft). That's going to have to change, otherwise it will look odd.
Additionally, the phone and social details (\phonesdetails and \socialsdetails, respectively) are actually assembled outside of the boxes they're used in via a loop structure, so we'll have to include that too (can also be found in moderncvheadi.sty).
Here's a final rendering of the layout, with pieces retrieved from the header style and assembled manually; no conditioning on left or right class options are needed, so that is removed:

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic} % <=============================================
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}         
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}  
\mobile{mobile phone}
\phone{phone (optional)} 
\email{email address} 
\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
% Set the first/last name
\firstnamestyle{\@firstname}~\lastnamestyle{\@lastname}%

% Add some space
\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}

% Create the phone and social details
\def\phonesdetails{}%
\collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
  \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
\def\socialsdetails{}%
\collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
  \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%

% Set the details component in a tabular
\addressfont\color{addresscolor}%
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l @{} }
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@born}}{}{\makenewline\bornsymbol\@born}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@homepageprotocol}{http}}{\httplink{\@homepage}}{\httpslink{\@homepage}}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}
\endgroup    

\section{Content}

\end{document}

